# List migrated questions at the top?

Tags: feature-request, migration, user-interface

My general practice for answering here at programmers.se is to browse the Questions list, scrolling down until I see ones that I've read before.  Lately I've noticed that a bit farther down, there will be one or two that I haven't seen before.  Then I see this:

> migrated from stackoverflow.com

Would it make more sense to have the migrated questions timestamped at the time they were migrated, rather than the time they were originally asked on the other site?

By the way, I'm very pleased that there's now an automated migration path from SO.

Comment: Agreed.  I browse questions the same way and have noticed this too.

Answer (score 2):

While not exactly what you're looking for, if you have 10k reputation, you have access to [a list of migrated questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated). You also have [the active tab](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active) in the questions list, which sorts the questions by their last activity, including their migration date.

The default sort for the [questions list](http://programmers.stackexchnage.com/questions), however, is unlikely to change from its current definition of "newest questions in absolute terms".